# Header back button is not working by default in react-navigation v3

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm using react-navigation v3 recently, so as using the `createStackNavigator` function for stack navigation. So as expected, it should return the default back button on the header in working condition.

But unfortunately, the back button renders perfectly but it's not being able to work.

Below is my code and I've separated a `routes.js` file for all sorts of navigation routes and importing in the screens accordingly subject to its use.

```
import ...
import ...
import ...

class Router extends Component{
  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      //...
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <Navigator />
    )
  }
}

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Landing
    },
    Login: {
        screen: Login
    },
    ResetPassword: {
      screen: ResetPassword
    },
    SetPassword: {
      screen: SetPassword
    },
    Signup: {
      screen: Signup
    },
    Dashboard: {
      screen: Dashboard
    },
    MealsRecipe: {
      screen: MealsRecipe
    }
},{
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    headerLayoutPreset: 'center'
})
const Navigator = createAppContainer(StackNavigator);

export default Router;
```

Can you please figure out the problem behind it?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of experiment, surprisingly I found that in `headerStyle:` giving `paddingBottom:` messes up the clicking functionality in the back button.

But had no idea, why this?
If anyone has any words about it then please do comment.

I had my `headerStyle` like below;

```
headerStyle: {
  height: 0,
  marginTop: 0,
  paddingTop: 10,
  paddingBottom: 30,
  backgroundColor: '#cb7429'
},
```